# Не отображаются contributions github

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Коммиты не отображаются в contributions на гите. Почта, которой делаю коммиты таже, что на гитхабе, репозиторий открыт. В репо, в который было около 15 коммитов за последний месяц последняя дата коммита числится на апрель. При этом код, который коммититься отображается.

Comment: `git push` делали?

Comment: Скриншот проблемы можно?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commits

Comment: да, все так как в документации

Comment: Не видя репозиторий сложно понять ошибку. Покажите ваш профиль.